# How to share folders from a container to another container using --link

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to dockerize a rails app and nginx with 2 separate containers. The rails app uses Unicorn and listens on a socket with static files serving from a folder. Now I need so somehow share the .sock and a folder to the NGINX container. This is how I ran 2 containers:

```
docker run -d --name app app:latest

docker run -d --name nginx -v /src/sockets:/src/sockets -v /src/public:/src/public --link app -p 80:80 nginx:latest
```

So expectedly, a `.sock` should be seen from `/src/sockets` inside Nginx container, but it becomes a folder instead, ie `/src/sockets/app.sock/`, and the static folder is empty.

Now these containers will be ran on AWS ECS, which is why I didn't use Docker-compose or share the volumes to host. I'm trying to mimic how ECS would work via Task Definition.

Comment: Hi, Do you looking for a shared volume to store app content and access from Nginx container? then you can try out EFS. Mount to host machine using user-data and using task definition use it to container.

Comment: EFS is too much for this thing I'm working on. For now I just use port instead of socket.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned the goal is to do this on ECS, instead of using --link, it's better to use a docker volume and use that to share a directory across containers on ECS. See [How to share file or directory with other container on ECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929954/how-to-share-file-or-directory-with-other-container-on-ecs/55929955#55929955)