# How to share file or directory with other container on ECS?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, docker-volume, sumologic

I have a Sumologic log collector which is a generic log collector. I want the log collector to see logs and a config file from a different container. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ECS containers can mount volumes so you would define

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "mountPoints": [
              {
                "sourceVolume": "logs",
                "containerPath": "/tmp/clogs/"
              },
        }
    ],
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "logs",
        }
    ]
}
```

ECS also has a nice UI you can click around to set up the volumes at the task definition level, and then the mounts at the container level.

Once that's set up, ECS will mount a volume at the container path, and everything inside that path will be available to all other containers that mount the volume.

Further reading:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html

Comment: This example is 100% match of the example from Amazon documentation titled "To provide an empty data volume for one or more containers".

I.e. everything in the path will not be available. 

To make it available, first container should define this path via VOLUME dockerfile directive

Answer (score 0):

To make the files from one container to be visible in another container, you need to have 2 things:

1. Volume in task definition, mounted to the paths in both containers
2. VOLUME directive in first image's Dockerfile with the path in first container

Example.

First container has path `/tmp/logs`

You want it in second container as `/tmp/first_container_logs`

In first dockerfile, you add

```
...
VOLUME ["/tmp/logs"]
```

You make task definition as

```
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
      ...
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "logs",
          "containerPath": "/tmp/logs"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      ...
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "logs",
          "containerPath": "/tmp/first_container_logs"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "logs",
    }
  ]
```